# SQL: How to select the row with the maximum value and another condition?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to select the row with the maximum score but since there can by many rows with maximums I want the row which has the highest value for another column. Consider that the values in this column are different. How do I write an SQLite query for this. This is my idea till now:

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(SCORE) FROM PLAYERS ORDER BY SECOND_COLUMN;
```

but it doesn't seem to work. How do I do that? Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want using `order by` and `limit`:

```
select p.*
from players p
order by score desc, second_column
limit 1;
```

Your query doesn't work because the `MAX(SCORE)` makes it an aggregation query.  However, there is no `GROUP BY`, so the `NAME` is a syntax error.  Also, `SECOND_COLUMN` in the `ORDER BY` is not defined, because of the aggregation.

Comment: I think it should be `second_column desc` as well

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT NAME, SCORE 
FROM PLAYERS 
WHERE SCORE>=(SELECT MAX(SCORE) FROM PLAYERS)
ORDER BY SECOND_COLUMN DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This would get all names with the same score then order by the second column and only return the maximum one

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(SCORE) FROM PLAYERS GROUP BY NAME ORDER BY MAX(SCORE);
```